# Excel VBA adding address of cells found to array

Tags: excel, vba

I have some code taken from cpearson.com find all page that let's me find all occurrences of my search value within a given range.

What I am looking to do is pass the .address of the cells found to an array to be used later in my code.

```
Dim desk As String
Dim rng As Range
Dim itm() As Variant
Dim lastc As Range
Dim found As Variant
Dim firstaddr As String

Set rng = Sheets("Inventory").Range("A1:A200")

desk = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TextFrame.Characters.Text

countd = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, desk)
'MsgBox desk
'MsgBox countd

With rng
    Set lastc = .Cells(.Cells.count)
End With

Set found = rng.find(desk, lastc, , xlWhole)

If Not found Is Nothing Then
    firstaddr = found.Address
End If

Do Until found Is Nothing
    ReDim Preserve itm(found.Address)  'get error 13 type mismatch here 
    itm(found.Address) = found.Address + 1
    'Debug.Print found.Address
    Set found = rng.FindNext(found)

    If found.Address = firstaddr Then
        Exit Do
    End If
Loop

End Sub
```

UPDATE:

```
Dim desk As String
Dim countd As Long    
Dim rng As Range
Dim itm()
Dim lastc As Range
Dim found As Range
Dim firstaddr As String
Dim i As Integer

Set rng = Sheets("Inventory").Range("A1:A200")

desk = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TextFrame.Characters.Text

countd = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, desk)
'MsgBox desk
'MsgBox countd
ReDim itm(countd)
With rng
    Set lastc = .Cells(.Cells.count)
End With

Set found = rng.find(desk, lastc, , xlWhole)

If Not found Is Nothing Then
    firstaddr = found.Address
End If
i = 0
Do Until found Is Nothing
    itm(i) = found.Address

    'Debug.Print found.Address
    Set found = rng.FindNext(found)

    If found.Address = firstaddr Then
        Exit Do
    End If
    i = i + 1
Loop

MsgBox "array is " & Join(itm, ", ")

End Sub
```

After some more googling and with the help of the 2 answers below I was able to do this to get the desired output without changing my code much.

Now to use each element of that array to search the cell to the right for a specific value then based its response grab the cell value of the one to the right of the cell being searched. But that should probably be another question.

Comment: can you provide a link to the code or the code itself?  And perhaps a mock up of what you would like?

Comment: WWW.cpearson.com/excel/findall.aspx

Comment: Just before the find all function on that page is where I got the code. Above the red line.

Comment: You want TestFindAll to print the addresses to an Array and not to console?

Comment: I don't see where you use use the `FindAll` function in the code.  Also `itm(found.Address)` and `ReDim Preserve itm(found.Address)` is undefined because `found.Address` is a string and not an Integer or Long.

Comment: While im not using the TestFindAll sub (should have specified above first red line) that is the desired outcome.

Answer (score 0):

CPearson's `FindAll` function returns a `Range` object.  To get an array containing the addresses, declare the array and loop over the contents of the array as done in `TestFindAll`:

```
Function GetAddresses(rng as Range) As String()

    Dim addresses() As String
    Redim addresses(rng.Count - 1)

    Dim i As Integer
    i = 0

    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In rng

        addresses(i) = cell.Address
        i = i + 1

    Next cell

    GetAddresses = addresses

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to find all occurrences of *"happiness"* in a worksheet and save the cell addresses in a dynamic array.  It uses **Find()** and **FindNext():**

```
Sub dural()
    Dim s As String, r As Range, ary() As String
    ReDim ary(1)
    s = "happiness"
    Set r = Cells.Find(What:=s, After:=Range("A1"))
    ary(UBound(ary)) = r.Address(0, 0)

    Do
        Set r = Cells.FindNext(After:=r)
        If r Is Nothing Then Exit Do
        If ary(1) = r.Address(0, 0) Then Exit Do
        ReDim Preserve ary(UBound(ary) + 1)
        ary(UBound(ary)) = r.Address(0, 0)
    Loop

    MsgBox UBound(ary)
End Sub
```